# Sharepoint logs me with the wrong user

Tags: sharepoint

I am using Sharepoint 2007 and IE 7.

I have my personal account, and also got from SA an account to use from a program.

At some point I wanted to check that the permissions of the program account were correctly set so I logged in with it. Since then, everytime I connect to the sharepoint it does not ask me for a password and logs me with the program user.

Closing the session does not work as it closes the IE and the next time I am automatically logged again; I have also deleted all offline content from the browser. I get it to work if I click in "Log in as Another user", but then when I start another session I am back at the program account.

This is really annoying, anyone can give me any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go into the credential Manager (on the client machine) and delete the credentials for the "wrong" username.

Comment: For whoever finds this useful --> Control Panel --> User accounts --> Advanced --> Manage Passwords. Names can change a little (I am translating from a Spanish language PC).

Answer (score 0):

Patrick answered it.

Control Panel --> User accounts --> Advanced --> Manage Passwords.

and also open ie right click on open ie keeping Shift press it should give you option to Run As Different user also can help you.

Comment: Please consider cutting down your answer to the new element you're contributing ("Run As Different User" not mentioned in the other answer). Also, please avoid abbreviations, and can you clarify the language? The answer's not entirely clear as it stands.

Comment: The OP posted the menu sequence in a comment on the accepted answer rather than editing it into that answer, so that part is already viewed as just clarification. Reposting it as an answer doesn't really add anything. The last sentence similarly appears to be supplementary information. So the posts doesn't seem to be an actual solution to the question that is substantively different from what has already been contributed. The appropriate way to post this kind of helpful information is in a comment, which requires a little more rep. Just a heads up that "non-answers" tend to attract downvotes.